# If i can access and use the this.props & this.state directly then why i have to call them via the super(props) in constructor in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, ecma

Let say i have a class component ***myPapa*** inside which is am not using any ***constructor*** or ***super()***:

```
class myPapap extends React.Component{
    render(){
        this.state          = {mom: 'dad'};
        this.props.brother  = 'sister';
        alert(this.state + ' ' + this.props);
        return(
            <View>
                Something ...
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Which works perfect and alerts:

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

Which means that it we can call the **this.props** and **this.state** and it is working. So, if this thing is working then why i have to do:

```
class myPapap extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state          = {mom: 'dad'};
        this.props.brother  = 'sister';
    }
}
```

Please can anyone tell in easy explanation with example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Firstly,

> The only place where you can assign this.state is the constructor.

As we all know, the reason why we use the `state` in React component is that whenever the component's state has updated, it will trigger the component to be re-rendered so that its presentation reflect the component's state. In order to leverage this advantage provided by the component's `state`, we have to obey the mechanism.

Moreover, the re-rendered process only happens when we update the component's state in an appropriate way which is using the `setState()` method.

[image]

For more information, you could find it here: [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

### Secondly,

Your code `this.props.brother = 'sister';` will not work for sure.

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/j354ypk645

You will get the error:

> Cannot add property brother, object is not extensible

The reason is, according to the React Document [Props Are Read Only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only), they said:

> Props are Read-Only
>
> Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, it must
>   never modify its own props.
>
> ...
>
> All React components must act like pure functions with respect to
>   their props.

### Finally,

According to the React Document, section [Constructor()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor), said:

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t
>   need to implement a constructor for your React component.

And

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.

Well then, you can use `this.props.brother` in order to retrieve the value of this property which is passed from a parent component. However, this is only for `get`, you are not supposed to `set` a value to it. The reason has been explained in part two of this answer.

Comment: So let say we have an element **<Abc name='myName'/>**, so the property **name** is set to **myName** in the component initialization internally by the React, which means later we cannot change it with **this.props.name**? Ha ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your examples is correct. You're not allowed to modify the `props` object your component receives ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)), so:

```
this.props.brother = 'sister';
```

is incorrect in both places. Either pass the `brother` prop from the container, or make `brother` a state property, not a props property.

Separately, in your second example, `this.state = ...` is incorrect. You're not allowed to assign directly to `this.state` anywhere but the constructor ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)).

Regarding why you have to have `super(props)`: It's because that's what sets up `this.props`, and the React framework relies on your doing it and never changing `props` directly (either what object the `props` property refers to, or the state of that object).

Comment: Sir basically my question is that if the **this.state** and **this.props** are available without using the **constructor and super()** then why we have to use the **constructor and super()** to made them accessible, because in that case the **constructor and super()** are useless because the **this.state** and **this.props** can be easily accessed without **constructor and super()**. Can you please explain sir?

Comment: @DaddyBoy - The answer is different for `props` and for `state`: For `props`: If you don't define a constructor in a `class`, the JavaScript engine creates one for you. When it's a subclass, that default constructor passes all arguments it receives to `super`. So that sets up `props`. For `state`: You aren't allowed to assign directly to `state` except in the constructor; React won't work correctly if you do. I suggest working through some basic React tutorials and reading through the documentation, which explains all of this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time sir. Stay blessed